# Are there any real magic folk working as professional magic acts in the Muggle world?

Tags: harry-potter

I heard that while public magic usage is generally banned and any trace cleaned up promptly, it's not always the case, such as when Muggle witnesses would attribute it to some more mundane explanations (eg. Lack of sleep, desert mirages etc.).

Accounting for such possible exceptions, have there been any real magic folk anywhere in the world who have openly used magic in the capacity of a performing magician, a Muggle entertainment act?

Comment: AFAIK, no mention in the books. But, that would be a damn good idea for the magical folk :)

Comment: I thought that is what Penn Jillette really is, that's why he makes such efforts to hide his real magic (despite turning up on so many "magic-y spell" type shows, and why he so completely pretends to be a absolute muggle....

Comment: I know that the Wikia is not canon, but we should check whether it is confirmed by canon that Indian "snake charmers" are actually wizards using Serpensortia.

Comment: @A.Darwin _The name "Snake Charmer" was given to them by the Muggles that **they entertain**. As their work is illicit for breaking the International Statute of Wizarding Secrecy, the Indian Ministry of Magic presumably punish them for their profession._ It's from HP wikia as well. But they don't perform it anymore.

Comment: @apollo how do you know that they don't perform anymore?

Comment: @A.Darwin Says so in the wikia you shared. Follow source links.

Comment: I don't want to insist on this topic , but I looked up both the wikia for Snake Charmers and the one for Serpensortia. They do say that Snake Charmers are punished by the Indian MoM, but they don't specifiy that they don't perform anymore. In fact, the Wikia (which IMO is not canon, anyway) seems to suggest thay they are still performing, by using the present tense: *The name "Snake Charmer" was given to them by the Muggles **that they entertain** *,*The Serpensortia Spell [...] **nowadays is used** worldwide [...]"* and so on.

Answer (score 14):

### No, there aren't.

Because it is against to *The International Statute of Wizarding Secrecy*.

> The International Statute of Wizarding Secrecy (also known as
>   International Statute of Secrecy) is a law in the wizarding world
>   that was first signed in 1689, then established officially in
>   1692. The law was laid down by the International Confederation of Wizards to safeguard the wizarding community from Muggles and hide its
>   presence from the world at large. - [Source](https://lawblog.justia.com/2010/11/18/introduction-to-wizarding-law/)

*However*...

In Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Fred and George (Weasley) visit a girl who works in a paper shop. They go there to entertain the girl with magic tricks:

> "We're off to the village, there's a very pretty girl working in the
>   paper shop who thinks my card tricks are something marvelous... *almost
>   like real magic*..." —George Weasley

This is the only mention of a real wizard performing magic tricks for a muggle (in the sense you are asking), which can be taken as a "*performing magician*", but not in the kind of performing magician who pulls a rabbit out of a hat.

Comment: What I'm looking for is an example of a real magician using spells in Muggle public space and Muggle witnesses thinking it's just "magic tricks" in the Muggle context. So there's no known instance in that sense?

Comment: @thegreatjedi No. Not that I know of. It is forbidden to perform real magic in front of muggles.

Comment: Could you add that rather crucial point (Statute of Secrecy) to your answer, @apollo?

Comment: @chirlu Didn't think it would be crucial since everyone knows that. _Done._

Comment: I think making a car fly is quite a feat.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman it is, but apparently there are no examples of performing magicians using flying cars (at least in the Potterverse!).

Comment: @CeesTimmerman It's not a _trick._ It's a complicated magic. What you suggest is far different than what was asked.

Comment: @apollo:
For that matter, it's slightly ambiguous as to whether George is actually using magic. Given his interest in pranks and other trickery, he might very well have learned sleight of hand and/or "Muggle magic" for the fun of it.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots That's why I put "_However_" in italic. George and Fred are the type of wizards who like expanding the rules. That was just a side note. My answer indicates there are no magical folks who use real magic to entertain muggles.